# «Залупа» — что означает данное прозвище, где ставить ударение?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, орфоэпия, история

> Князь Иван Петрович Охлябинин, по прозвищу Залупа († после 1576) —
> русский военный и государственный деятель в эпоху правления Ивана IV
> Васильевича Грозного, сын боярский и голова, опричник, воевода,
> единственный сын князя Петра Васильевича Охлябинина.

"Залупа" — что означает данное прозвище, где ударение ставить в этом слове?

(В интернете пишут, что князь Иван Петрович — якобы предок актёра Ивана Охлобыстина! Поэтому и возник интерес к прозвищу, ведь то, что Залупа — предок Охлобыстина, очень интересно!)

Answer (score 6):

В словарях (Даля, толковом и русского арго) ударение одно — *залу́па*.
А версии происхождения и значения этого прозвища имеются в статье Вадима Нестерова ["О рюриковиче, которого все звали Залупа"](https://author.today/post/34830).

Вот выдержки:
*Почему он получил такое прозвище — существуют две версии.

Первое — он просто был лысым, и голова его была как "залупленнное" (очищенное от скорлупы) яйцо. Это чтобы не шокировать вас другим сравнением.

Вторые уверяют, что не только прямое, но и переносное значение слова "залупаться" во времена Ивана Грозного было ровно тем же самым, что и сегодня. Вот как его определяет академический "Словарь русского арго":

ЗАЛУПАТЬСЯ, -аюсь, -аешься, несов. (сов. ЗАЛУПИТЬСЯ, -уплюсь, -упишься). 1. на кого и без доп. Нагло себя вести, проявлять гонор; выставлять себя напоказ.*

Значение слова *залупа*, а также глаголов *залупать/залупить* и *залупаться/залупиться* можно посмотреть в словаре русских народных говоров ([стр. 224](https://iling.spb.ru/vocabula/srng/srng_10.pdf)).
У Даля есть такие значения: [залупывать](https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) — что, задирать кожу, заворачивать; залупина ж. залупленое, задраное место, порча; залупщик м. залупщица ж. кто залупает или задирает что.

Пофантазировала о том, что было 450 лет назад (лихой вояка, боярский сын), и предположила, что в современном языке, возможно, это слово бы имело значение "задира".

Comment: Стр. 224: О том, кто ходит, задрав, подняв платье. О ребёнке с высоко поднятой рубашкой. ЗАЛУПА ТЫ ТАКА! НЕМА ТЕБЕ СОРОМУ ХОДИТЬ ТАК! Поэтому я в меру своего развития тоже пофантазировала о возможных предках Охлобыстина!

Comment: Ой, Алёнушка, Вам не понравились мои предположения? Ну... Я предпочитаю *фантазировать* в лучшую сторону.

Comment: Мне всё понравилось! :)